# Access dynamically rendered children's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a system to multi-select elements from a FlatList to then remove from AsyncStorage the data related to the selected elements. How it works is:

-Parent component passes to child inside FlatList a state that will hold children's functions, like this:

```
export default function Parent({ navigation }) {
   const [ productsInfo, setProductsInfo ] = useState([]);
   const [ selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts ] = useState([]);
   const [ selectCount, setSelectCount ] = useState(0);

   <FlatList data={productsInfo}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Child item={item}
            selectedProducts={selectedProducts}
            selectCount={selectCount}
            setSelectCount={setSelectCount}/>
        )}/>
```

-Children components fill parent's array state with their callback functions:

```
const Child = ({ item, selectedProducts, selectCount, setSelectCount }) => {
    const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        selectedProducts.push([selected, setSelected]); //filling parent's state
    }, []);
```

-Parent handles children's state through callback functions passed on previous step (with useEffect)

```
export default function Parent({ navigation }) {
    const [ selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts ] = useState([]);
    const [ selectCount, setSelectCount ] = useState(0);

const selectAll = () => {
        selectedProducts.map(product => {
            let setSelected = product[1]; //second element is the setState of child
            setSelected(true);
        });
        setSelectCount(selectedProducts.length);
    }
```

-Children handle their own state when they're pressed:

```
const Child = ({ item, selectedProducts, selectCount, setSelectCount }) => {
    const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState(false);

    const handleSelect = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
        let count = selected ? selectCount - 1 : selectCount + 1;
        setSelectCount(count); //parent's state
    }
```

Now this all works, everything gets highlighted correctly and the counter of selected elements checks out. The problem is when I go to confirm deletion of selected elements (or the data they're rendered upon) and I iterate through the children's boolean state. They all turn out as false, even if they're true since they are highlighted, since they change color based on that state.

```
export default function Parent({ navigation }) {

const deleteSelected = async () => {
        await selectedProducts.map(product => {
            let selected = product[0]; //first element is the state's value, boolean
            console.log(selected); //all false
        });
    }
```

It needs to know at which index there are true value so it can delete data at those indexes, but they never turn out true.
Do you know why this happens? I'll leave the whole code below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { TouchableNativeFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Product = ({ item, selectedProducts, selectCount, setSelectCount }) => { //Child
    const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState(false);

    const handleSelect = () => {
        setSelected(!selected);
        let count = selected ? selectCount - 1 : selectCount + 1;
        setSelectCount(count);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        selectedProducts.push([selected, setSelected]);
    }, []);

    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => handleSelect()}>
            <View style={[styles.productContainer, {backgroundColor: selected ? '#DDDDDD' : '#F8F8F8'}]}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.productTitle}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.productDetailsContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.productDetails}>
                        <Text style={styles.productDetailsTitle}>Prezzo attuale</Text>
                        <Text>{item.currentPrice}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.productDetails}>
                        <Text style={styles.productDetailsTitle}>Prezzo più basso</Text>
                        <Text>{item.lowestPrice}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.productDetails}>
                        <Text style={styles.productDetailsTitle}>Prezzo target</Text>
                        <Text>{item.targetPrice}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>);
}


export default function WatchlistDeleteScreen({ navigation }) { //Parent
    const [ productsInfo, setProductsInfo ] = useState([]);
    const [ selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts ] = useState([]);
    const [ selectCount, setSelectCount ] = useState(0);

    const selectAll = () => {
        selectedProducts.map(product => {
            let setSelected = product[1];
            setSelected(true);
        });
        setSelectCount(selectedProducts.length);
    }


    const deleteSelected = async () => {
        await selectedProducts.map(product => {
            let selected = product[0];
            console.log(selected);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            await AsyncStorage.getItem('productsInfo')
            .then(data => JSON.parse(data))
            .then(jsonData => {
                setProductsInfo(jsonData);
            })
            .catch(error => {});
        }

        getData();
    }, []);


    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <View style={styles.headerIconsContainer}>
                    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => { navigation.pop() }}
                    background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('default', true)}>
                        <Icon name={'close'} size={27} color={'black'} />
                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, marginLeft: 25}}>{selectCount}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.headerIconsContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.icons}>
                        <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => { selectAll() }}
                        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('default', true)}>
                            <Icon name={'select-all'} size={27} color={'black'} />
                        </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                    </View>
                    {selectCount > 0 &&
                    <View style={styles.icons}>
                        <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => { deleteSelected() }}
                        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('default', true)}>
                                <Icon name={'check'} size={27} color={'black'} />
                        </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                    </View>}
                </View>
            </View>
            <FlatList data={productsInfo}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Product item={item}
                selectedProducts={selectedProducts}
                selectCount={selectCount}
                setSelectCount={setSelectCount}/>
            )}/>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: 58,
        elevation: 4,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    headerIconsContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    screenTitle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20
    },
    productContainer: {
        padding: 10
    },
    productTitle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 19,
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        borderBottomWidth: 0.2
    },
    productDetailsTitle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 14
    },
    productDetailsContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        padding: 5,
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    productDetails: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    icons: {
        marginLeft: 25
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

This is wrong:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        selectedProducts.push([selected, setSelected]);
    }, []);
```

The `selectedProducts` is a state variable and should be considered immutable: `push` does not mutates the variable itself (its the same array), but adds an element to it (a side effect). You should avoid this and only use `setSelectedProducts` instead. Even more, in the browser `console` you should have a message warning about `useEffect` not having the correct dependencies array. Try this instead:

```js
// Add extra argument setSelectedProducts
const Child = ({ item, selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts, selectCount, setSelectCount }) => {
    const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
       // Filling parent's state
       setSelectedProducts([
         ...selectedProducts,
         [selected, setSelected],
       ]);
    }, [setSelectedProducts, selectedProducts, selected, setSelected]);
```

Now, this shows part of the problem here: there are circular dependencies. In this *fixed* `useEffect` example, it will be fired each time one or more of its dependencies changes. As we are changing `selectedProducts` in the callback (indirectly, using `setSelectedProducts`), it will be called again, and again, and again.

#### The solution

You need to pass the responsibility of managing the list of states (and, thus, the list of selected ones) to the list containing them (here, `WatchlistDeleteScreen`). This will receive a *(un)select me* message from each product:

```js
const Product = ({ item, selected, toggleSelected }) => { //Child
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={toggleSelected}> // Without `()`: No extra function
    //...
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

export default function WatchlistDeleteScreen({ navigation }) { //Parent
  const [ productsInfo, setProductsInfo ] = useState([]);
  const [ selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts ] = useState([]);

  // Mark all products as selected
  const selectAll = () => {
    setSelectedProducts(
      productsInfo.map(() => true)
    );
  }

  // Mark all products as unselected
  const deleteSelected = () => {
    setSelectedProducts(
      productsInfo.map(() => false)
    );
  }

  // Toggles a single product selection state
  const toggleSelected = (index) => {
    const selectedProductsNew = 
      selectedProducts.map(
        // Only toggle the matching index product
        (poductState, i) => i === index ? !value : value
      );

    // But full array is updated, respecting React
    // immutability and state change controller
    setSelectedProducts( selectedProductsNew );
  }

  // Fetch items. No need to async/await if you use .then/.catch
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('productsInfo')
      .then(data => JSON.parse(data))
      .then(jsonData => {
        setProductsInfo(jsonData);
        // Also create an array with the states of all
        // products to unselected
        deleteSelected();
      })
      .catch(error => {});
  }, [setProductsInfo, deleteSelected]);

  // Just to be clear. You can use selectedProducts.length directly
  // from the JSX
  const selectCount = selectedProducts.length;

  return (
    // ...
       <FlatList
         data={productsInfo}
         // Also get `index` from FlatList
         // https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem
         renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <Product
              item={item}
              // Pass `selected` state (managed in parent, used in child)
              selected={selectedProducts[index]}
              // Pass `index` to the `toggleSelected` function
              toggleSelected={toggleSelected.bind(this, index)}/>
         )}
       />
    // ...
  )
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe FlatList has an index property... I would have done it this way if I knew it. I solved it before reading your answer by passing a function from parent to children so that when they're selected they call said function providing the index to the father by looping through an object and comparing the url of the product... Not proud of my solution. I am definitely correcting it to your solution. Learned a lot, thank you so much!